# facebook graph api page create feed images

Tags: php, python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Please help. I post for the page.

```
{PAGE-ID}/feed {message: "test string"}
```

I can attach as attachment link)

```
{PAGE-iD}/feed {message: "asd", name: "asd", link:"http://example.com/1.jpg", caption:"asd", description: "asd"}
```

It works))
to upload pictures to facebook, I also know how))

```
{PAGE-ID}/photos {url: "http://example.com/1.jpg"}
```

How do I create a post with images, but without links? I want to make text and a few pictures.
[For example like this](https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=1288183324604330&id=1280431668712829)

Comment: “Foo added 2 new photos” is the kind of aggregate post Facebook creates automatically after Foo has uploaded several new images.

Comment: Could you help me fully understand the steps.
I need to create a publication in which text and pictures.
I've uploaded the photos {page-ID}/photos
How am I going to make a post with pictures and text?

Comment: You can post a caption together with the photo.

Comment: I can make a post with one picture. And how to make with multiple?

Comment: Again: You can’t. Facebook decides when to display those aggregate posts.

Comment: Again)) I want to make a post like the example on the link. How do I implement this using Graph API? If you go on {PAGE-ID}/photos I can upload one photo instead of several. How can I make some?))

Comment: What part of you can’t, and Facebook creates those posts automatically, don’t you understand …? You can post multiple single photos, one after the other - and then Facebook may or may not decide to show them in that format.

Comment: I don't understand. Show me an example of CURL request please.